# Why is testing accuracy consistently higher than training accuracy ? Possible interpretations?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I am trying to compare the outcome of machine learning algorithms given different types of simulated data, and no matter what dataset I use I am consistently getting a lower validation accuracy than testing accuracy, which to me seems strange.

As far as I can tell, I am not falling into the common pitfalls:  Train/Test set is 70/30 split, stratified, and on top of this I use many (1000) different splits to ensure results are not due to luck.  I am using Leave One Out Cross Validation on the training set to assess the validation accuracy.  Is there another possible explanation for this strange behavior?

Attached is the GitHub repository where I have a walkthrough of what I have tried, and if anyone could help me understand what I am potentially doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.  If you need more information to answer my question, let me know!

https://github.com/ScoobSharkason/sturdy-lamp

**Edit: I made some slight adjustments to the ipynb file to make it more plug and play friendly.  Let me know if any errors pop up as it is possible I forgot something else.**

Comment: Does this effect persist even when you change some of the `random_state` values in the code?

Comment: Yes it does, I have tried changing the 'random_state' for 'make_classification' , 'train_test_split' , and establishing the 'LogisticRegression()' estimator, although my bad for not showing that in the code